# Drush fails with "No release history was found for the requested project ..."

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, makefile, localhost, drush

I am new to Drupal and I have a problem with installing Drupal using Drush (at the command prompt).

After I generate a Drush make file named  **test.make**, using http://drushmake.me/ , I wonder how I can install Drupal using this Drush make file in localhost?

I use this command in one directory: `drush make test.make -y`

After doing so, this warning shows up:

> No release history was found for the requested project (test).

How can I resolve this warning and get Drupal installed (using this make file)?

Comment: Do you have drush make installed? i think Drush 5 includes it but older versions require drush make be installed. What's the contents of the make file (test.make)?

Comment: Yes I have the Drush 5 Installed. I have generated the .make file in http://drushmake.me/ . I dont know how to install drupal with selected modules from drushmake.me :/

This is my test.make http://drushmake.me/file.php?token=7f428f339b68&raw

Comment: Its best to cut/paste the content of your make file as part of your question because the error indicates there is something wrong with the syntax/content of the make file.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it may be hard to tell, for sure there is something wrong within the content of your make file. More specifically, consider the actual message you got, which is:

> No release history was found for the requested project (test).

The "(test)" at the end of the message, is a reference to the Drupal module that you are trying to process in your make file, which you have named "test.make". There is nothing wrong in the name of your make file, only a bit confusing because of the "test" part in it. And the actual message you get is related to "module" named "test". Here is a variation of what this error message is trying to tell you: I cannot find any Drupal module on drupal.org, with a name of "test". And that is because https://www.drupal.org/project/test causes a 404 error (page not found).

There are multiple variations of this problem that lead to similar error messages. Here is just 1 of them: module [USASearch](https://www.drupal.org/project/usasearch), is case sensitive (as explained also in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1715486)). Look at the "Browse code repository" URL on the project page of this module to see how confusing it may get ...

**Bottomline**: my experience so far has been that whenever I get this typical Drush message, it's because I made some typo in my module name, or I refer to a module that simply does not exists.

Does this answer help?

Answer (score 0):

The way how Drush is checking for release version, is by the following URL:

- https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/project_name/7.x

So make sure your `project_name` (test) is the valid machine name of the project which is published on drupal.org, by editing your make file.

Here are the `curl` commands demonstrating both non-working and working scenarios:

```
$ curl -s https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/non-existing/7.x
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<error>No release history was found for the requested project (non-existing).</error>

$ curl -s https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x | head -n10
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<title>Views</title>
<short_name>views</short_name>
<dc:creator>merlinofchaos</dc:creator>
<type>project_module</type>
<api_version>7.x</api_version>
<recommended_major>3</recommended_major>
<supported_majors>3</supported_majors>
<default_major>3</default_major>
...
```

If your project isn't hosted on Drupal, you need to specify/define your custom package handler by `--package-handler` parameter (see: `drush help up`).

See also: [D7 registry_autoload: No release history was found for the requested project](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246819/1908).